# How to grant OAuth access to an unlinked MCC account?

Tags: google-ads-api

I've been using Adwords API on an MCC account without any issues. Now I got a new MCC account which I don't want to link with the first MCC account. Is it possible to use the same OAuth credentials and refresh token on the new MCC account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the Google account for which you created your OAuth2 refresh token has access to both MCCs, then yes, you can use them without a problem. You'll need to specify the client ID of the account you want to access in your API calls as usual.